# iOS - UICollectionView still have spacing between cells after set to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Im getting small spaces between cells when setting everything to 0. All I did in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is setting `backgroundColor` for each cell.

Here's my code:

```
//collectionView frame
_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 150) collectionViewLayout:layout];

...

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //The cell sizes are divided by the width of the collectionView. 
    return CGSizeMake(_collectionView.frame.size.width/12, _collectionView.frame.size.width/12);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

My collection view looks like this. You'll see that there are black lines between some cells. What is causing this? How can I remove the lines?

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too faced this issue. I believe this happens because of a bug in autolayout. That 1px gap between the cells cant be removed, unless you do some crazy hack!!!

Comment: did you try ceil(_collectionView.frame.size.width/12)?

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this problem. Thanks to @tenric for pointing out and yes for me was because the width is not divisible by the number of desired columns. My solution as follow:

```
var itemWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return floor(view.frame.size.width / 7)
    }
}
```

And because I'm using AutoLayout, I just adjust the gap to the width of the collectionView as follow (refer to widthAnchor):

```
collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerSeparator.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerSeparator.topAnchor).isActive = true

let gap = view.frame.size.width - (itemWidth * 7)
collectionViewWidthConstraint = collectionView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -gap)
```

Answer (score 0):

because both width and height are not divisible by 12,so it would remain some empty pixel point.To avoid this,both width and height of collectionView should be multiples of 12.

Comment: I did change the size is each cell to 26.6666667 (320/12) and still this is happening. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was going crazy over this too. I wanted a generic solution since I had 3 cells per row for iPhones and 4 cells per row for iPads and the UICollectionView was covering the entire width of the screen and the width is different between all devices.

I ended up making the combined width of the cells on a row wider than the device screen by using ceil(frame.width / itemsPerRow). I then calculated the total width of the cells on a row and compared with the screen width (view.frame) to get the width overflow the cells would create. Knowing the overflow I set the trailing constraint of the UICollectionView to be negative the overflow. This means the UICollectionView is actually going to overflow the screen width with a pixel or so, but in my case this was not an issue. Hopefully the code below will help clarify and give you an idea of how this could be solved.

```
// calculating cell width
let frame = view.frame
let cellWidth = ceil(frame.width / itemsPerRow)

// adjust UICollectionView to avoid space between cells
let totalCellsWidth = cellWidth * itemsPerRow
let overflow = totalCellsWidth - frame.width
let adjustedConstraint = -overflow
collectionViewsTrailingConstraint.constant = adjustedConstraint
```